# how to set imageview as url by using extra

Tags: android, url, android-studio, imageview, extra

I am trying to change the image of a scrollview with a custom imageview but I am un sue of how to set the imageview to show a url

```
public class NewsDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    coordinatorLayout= (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.newsscroll);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contenttext);
    tv.setText(extra.getString("Message"));
    ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_img2);
    im.set
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure to understand your question, but if what you're trying to do is loading an image from a URL into an ImageView, you have several options:

- Use a library to do it for you. Some of them are: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), etc...
- Download the image from the internet using a network library and then set it to the ImageView as a bitmap (this is basically reinventing the wheel as the previous mentioned libs are quite good and reliable.)